# Is Hellinger transformation suitable to access species abundance - environmental variable relationships?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, vegan, hellinger

While working with a multivariate dataset, I noticed that Hellinger transformation reveals relationships with the dataset I did not see otherwise. The fact that a transformation affects species abundance - environmental variable relationships is, of course, nothing new. However, I guess I am a bit skeptical about Hellinger transformation based relationships since I do not completely understand how the data are transformed. OK, the equation is simple enough (stated for example [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs004420100716)), but the transformation itself is not as intuitive as for example logarithm transformation. Here is an example using a subset of my dataset in R (looking at the plot should be enough to answer this question, but I paste a reproducible example in case someone wants it):

Copy the dataset from [here](https://pastebin.com/dpiRP2bH) and assign to `x`

```
x$sp1.hel <- x$sp1.raw
x$sp2.hel <- x$sp2.raw

x$sp1.log <- log(x$sp1.raw + 1)
x$sp2.log <- log(x$sp2.raw + 1)

library(vegan)

x[c("sp1.hel", "sp2.hel")] <- vegan::decostand(x[c("sp1.hel", "sp2.hel")], method = "hellinger")

library(reshape2)

mx <- reshape2::melt(x, id = "envvar")

mx$trans <- factor(sapply(strsplit(as.character(mx$variable), "\\."), "[", 2))

levels(mx$trans) <- c("Hellinger", "Log + 1", "None")

mx$species <- factor(sapply(strsplit(as.character(mx$variable), "\\."), "[", 1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mx, aes(x = envvar, y = value, color = species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_grid(trans~species, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As you can see, there is probably no relationship between sp1 abundance and envvar in non-transformed or log + 1 transformed data, but such relationship becomes apparent for Hellinger transformed data. Sp2 seems to somewhat positively correlate with envvar regardless the transformation (see `cor(x)`).

If I was to Hellinger transform my dataset for a constrained multivariate ordination (RDA / CCA), I would probably end up concluding that sp1 and envvar have a rather strong relationship, even though such relationship is not evident for non-transformed or log-transformed data.

Therefore I am wondering whether Hellinger transformation is a suitable method to examine species community - environmental variable relationships in constrained multivariate ordinations?

Comment: PS. I have read the article I linked many times. While they seem to conclude that Hellinger transformation is a suitable method, they do not really discuss/examine the changes in relationships with environmental variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hellinger transformation of vector of abundances is

$$
y_{ij}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{y_{ij}}{y_{i+}}}
$$

where I'm using $y_{i+}$ to indicate the sample total count over all $j = 1, \dots, m$ species, for the $i$th sample.

The first part, the fraction, turns abundances into proportional values out of the sample total count. In other words we are now very much thinking about *relative species composition*, not the magnitudes of abundance values.

The square root element is a commonly-applied transformation for moderately skewed data. Here it is reducing the effect of those $y_{ij}$ values that may be extremely large. It is similar in effect to the log transformation but not as strong a transformation.

The way it is presented in the linked paper ([Legendre & Gallagher, 2001](https://doi.org/10.1007/s004420100716)) is very much in the context of applying certain *linear* methods to transformed data such that "non-linear" analyses can be performed.

I would argue that your conclusion re `sp1` is not self evident from the plot you show; to my eye there is a tendency for larger *abundances* towards the middle of `envvar`. But that is totally irrelevant in the context of the Hellinger transformed data because now we must consider the *relative* composition and hence we must consider `sp2` and it is clear that this species increases in *abundance* with increasing values of `envvar` and, assuming that `sp1` has no relationship with `envvar` at all, `sp2`'s *relative* contribution to the composition of the community must increase, and therefore that of `sp1` must decrease, as a function of increasing `envvar`. This is consistent with the panels containing Hellinger transformed data that you show.

Comment: Excellent answer! I think I finally got it! :)